# Zend url : get parameter always stay in the url

Tags: zend-framework, url, parameters, get

I have some trouble using the Zend url helper with get parameter.
In a view, I have pagination which send extra parameters in get (so in the url), so that's ok. But that is not ok is that the parameters always stay in the url even if I change page. 
In fact, the zend url helper - I use to generate the url of link or form's action - add automaticaly the parameter at the end of the url so whatever the link I click, I have this parameters...

```
//In my controller
$this->_view->url(array("action"=>"action-name");
// generate for example : "mywebsite/controller-name/action-name/pays/4" but I don't want the "/pays/4"
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `url` method accepts additional parameters. One of them resets the `get-string` parameters.

> url  (
>
> array $  urlOptions = array(),
>         $  name = null,
>         $  reset = false,
>         $  encode = true
>    )
>    Generates an url given the name of a route.
>
> Parameters:
>
> array  $urlOptions - Options passed to the assemble method of the Route object.
>    mixed  $name - The name of a Route to use. If null it will use the current Route
>    bool  $reset - Whether or not to reset the route defaults with those provided
>
> Returns:
>   string Url for the link href attribute.

It's all in the doc. The above is for ZF version 1.10

Answer (score 2):

The definition or url() is

```
public function url(array $urlOptions = array(), $name = null, $reset = false, $encode = true)
```

So try setting the third parameter ($reset) to true