# Remove parameters from URL in url()?

Tags: php, zend-framework, url

In the Zend framework, I am using the `$this->url()` method and it's working like a charm. I have one problem though: the method seems to copy the current request parameters over to the new URL. I want it to stop doing this.

An example: I use `$this->url('controller' => 'blog', 'action' => 'list');`. If the current page is `www.foo.bar/item/view/id/1` with `id` being a parameter, the URL will become:

```
www.foo.bar/blog/list/id/1
```

You can see the `/id/1` part is retained without me specifying it.

How can I make it stop doing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's another discussion similar to this.. Might be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993725/removing-parameters-from-url-when-using-url-view-helper-links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to this duplicate question, it's on an older version of ZF, but it should point you in the right direction:

[Zend url : get parameter always stay in the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8943502/zend-url-get-parameter-always-stay-in-the-url)

Comment: Thanks! I knew there had to be something like this. Apologies for the redundant question.

Answer (score 1):

Set any parameter you don't want to keep to `null`:

```
$this->url('controller' => 'blog', 'action' => 'list', 'id'=>null);
```

**EDIT**
There is one more way. In fact, all url helpers does is a pass through call to router:

```
 public function url(array $urlOptions = array(), $name = null, $reset = false, $encode = true)
        {
            $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
            return $router->assemble($urlOptions, $name, $reset, $encode);
        }
```

As you can see, the third parameter (boolean $reset) should reset any parameters stored in the current route. Assuming you are using the standard router (`Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite`) the call will be passed to a route (possibly some descendant of Zend_Controller_Router_Route), and should be interpreted as such. Of course if you use your own Route, you should take care of this yourself.

Comment: Is this the only way? There may be any number of parameters used throughout the website. It would be a bit annoying to have to check for them all every time.

Comment: there is some switch (that I don't remember) that clears the parameters, but if you only need to remove id, this way is shorter :-) I will add an edit.